# No handlers could be found for logger 'matplotlib.lengend'

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256, endpoint=True)
C, S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)

plt.plot(X, S, color = 'green', linewidth = 1.0, linestyle = '-')
plt.plot(X, C, color = 'blue', linewidth = 1.0, linestyle = '-')

plt.xlim(-4.0, 4.0)

plt.xticks(np.linspace(-4, 4, 9, endpoint=True))

plt.ylim(-1.0, 1.0)

plt.yticks(np.linspace(-1, 1, 5, endpoint=True))

plt.legend(loc = 'upper left', frameon = False)

plt.show()
```

When I run this python code I see the plots but not the legend and get the output as: `No handlers could be found for logger "matplotlib.legend"`

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add label to plot() function. After adding, it's working fine.